# How to make nosetests print unicode readable?

Tags: python, unicode, nose

I am using `nosetests` to run test, but I find that it cannot print the real unicode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import unittest

class FooTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_str(self):
        print("中国")
        self.assertEqual(1, 0)

    def test_unicode(self):
        print(u"中国")
        self.assertEqual(1, 0)

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

its captured result is like this:

```
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
\u4e2d\u56fd

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

What I want is:

```
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
中国

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `-s` or `--nocapture` option will prevents `nosetest` to capture standard output; You will see the string as you want, but without `>> beging/end captured stdout<<` marker as the `print` statemnet will print the string as soon as it's executed:

```
$ nosetests -s t.py
中国
F中国
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_str (t.FooTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 9, in test_str
    self.assertEqual(1, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

======================================================================
FAIL: test_unicode (t.FooTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 13, in test_unicode
    self.assertEqual(1, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Another options: Use python 3! No option is required:

```
$ python3 -m nose t.py
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_str (t.FooTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 9, in test_str
    self.assertEqual(1, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
中国

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
FAIL: test_unicode (t.FooTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 13, in test_unicode
    self.assertEqual(1, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
中国

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with probably same root cause. If you run tests with `LC_CTYPE=C nosetests` Python unable to encode unicode characters out of ASCII encoding since locale dictates `C`. Running with something `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 nosetest` should fix that.

P.S. I'm looking for solution how to indicate this in test itself of nosetest runner.